# ExtJS check box theme change

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, checkbox, styles

I've been using a checkbox (xtype: checkbox) and even though the code is the same as in the examples I get a different style of checkbox than the normal html one:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2M4K7.jpg

It is the second element on the right of the combobox. It is hardly visible and not pretty. The problem is that the documentation doesn't have anything on this because for some reason they get the normal checkboxes. I tried checking some CSS stuff but tbh I'm lost. Any ideas?

```
var getVersionsRoutings = Ext.create('widget.checkbox', {boxLabel: ' XXXX', name: 'versionsCheckbox', id:'verCheckbox'});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that checkbox is not a real checkbox but button that is styled to look like a checkbox. You would need to provide your own sprites for unchecked and checked images to restyle it. The influential css classes are:

```
.x-form-cb-checked .x-form-checkbox 
.x-form-checkbox
```

and possibly also other.

Comment: Are you sure? If you check this page: 
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/extjs-build/examples/themes/index.html 
all the checkbox examples are normal and we use the same theme.

Comment: Yeah, I am. If you click the link you posted and explore the rendered html of "Bar" checkbox you see `<input type="button" id="checkboxfield-1079-inputEl" class="x-form-field x-form-checkbox" autocomplete="off" hidefocus="true" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="" style="-webkit-user-select: text;">` Not a checkbox, but button.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Not only that but I found out that this image actually appears because we were using richfaces before trying to transition into extjs and is overriding the extjs combobox images. When we remove richfaces completely I guess it will turn back to the normal combobox.